# How to join the same column more than once and show it in a page

Tags: join

I want to join the same column three times then display each different value in my page. 
I hope someone can find the problem. It shows the same language three times and it also shows the third one not the first one.

[My Query][1]

```
<?php
include '../config.php';

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = " SELECT  *
FROM master_student_info 
INNER JOIN master_streams a ON master_student_info.stream_id = a.mst_stream_id
INNER JOIN master_streams b ON master_student_info.stream2_id = b.mst_stream_id
INNER JOIN master_streams c ON master_student_info.stream3_id = c.mst_stream_id
INNER JOIN master_schedules d ON master_student_info.schedule_id = d.mst_schedule_id
INNER JOIN master_schedules e ON master_student_info.schedule2_id = e.mst_schedule_id
INNER JOIN master_schedules f ON master_student_info.schedule3_id = f.mst_schedule_id
INNER JOIN master_cities ON city_id = mst_city_id 
WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];   

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$th=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
?>
```

[master_student_info table][2]

```
id, name, email, mobile, dob, fname, fmobile, mname, mmobile, city_id, address, stream_id, stream2_id, stream3_id, schedule_id, schedule2_id, schedule3_id, doa, picture,  how_id, cbox1, cbox2
```

[master stream table][3]

```
mst_stream_id, mst_stream_name
```

[master stream fields][4]

```
mst_stream_id      mst_stream_name
1                     English
2                     German
3                     Japanese
4                     French
5                     Italian
```

[my code][5]

```
       <li class="list-group-item">
          <b> Language 1</b> <a id="stream_id" class="pull-right" > <?= $th['mst_stream_name']?> </a>
        </li>


        <li class="list-group-item">
          <b> Language 2</b> <a id="stream2_id" class="pull-right" > <?= $th['mst_stream_name']?> </a>


        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <b> Language 3</b> <a id="stream3_id" class="pull-right" > <?= $th['mst_stream_name']?> </a>
        </li>
```

[master student info example][7]

```
id = 1
name = name
stream_id = 1
stream2_id = 2
stream3_id = 3
```

Comment: Is that a better format?

Comment: Thanks for doing this +1.